# After updating ValidTimeState table, how to find previous record? Specifically postal address

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

When I take a `LogisticsPostalAddress` record and update it, it creates a new record and expires the old record because it's a ValidTimeState table.  This makes sense to me, but is there a way to find out what the old record was?

I do not want to do a `ValidTimeStateUpdate::Correction` type update because I do want the new record.

Comment: Occasionally [xRecord.orig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xrecord.orig.aspx)() is your friend.

Comment: I tried this, didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: The `orig()` must be called before `update()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use validTimeState in your select query with a range smaller then your current from date.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg843767.aspx

> SELECT validTimeState(dateFrom, dateTo)
>   * from table

or

> SELECT
>           validTimeState(dateTarget)
>           * from xEP